# How to resize comments on selected range instead of whole sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, range

The following code auto resizes comments (notes) in my Excel spreadsheet.

The code is slow. To speed it up I wish to specify a smaller range not the whole sheet. Let's say cells A1 to B10.

```vb
Sub NotesResize()

Dim MyComments As Comment
Dim lArea As Long

For Each MyComments In ActiveSheet.Comments
    With MyComments
        .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        If .Shape.Width > 300 Then
            lArea = .Shape.Width * .Shape.Height
            .Shape.Width = 200
            ' An adjustment factor of 1.1 seems to work ok.
            .Shape.Height = (lArea / 200) * 1.1
        End If
    End With
Next ' comment
End Sub
```

I tried setting ranges as follows.

I get

> Run time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

```vb
Sub NotesResizeSelection()

Dim MyComments As Comment
Dim lArea As Long
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Range("A1:B10")

For Each MyComments In rng2.Comments
    With MyComments
        .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        If .Shape.Width > 300 Then
            lArea = .Shape.Width * .Shape.Height
            .Shape.Width = 200
            ' An adjustment factor of 1.1 seems to work ok.
            .Shape.Height = (lArea / 200) * 1.1
        End If
    End With
Next ' comment
End Sub
```

Comment: Not tested but shapes have a `topleftcell` property which you might be able to utilise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `range` object does not have a collection of `comments` so your call to `rng2.Comments` is invalid, hence the error.
`Comments` is a property of the `Worksheet` object.

What you could do is verify if the active comment is in the selected range? Though this would still loop through all the comments?

Like below:

```
Sub NotesResizeSelection()

Dim MyComments As Comment
Dim lArea As Long
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Range("A1:B10")

minRow = rng2.row
maxRow = minRow + rng2.Rows.Count - 1
minColumn = rng2.Column
maxColumn = minColumn + rng2.columns.Count - 1

For Each Comment In ActiveSheet.Comments
    cRow = Comment.Parent.row
    cCol = Comment.Parent.Column
    If (cRow >= minRow And cRow <= maxRow) And (cCol >= minColumn And cCol <= maxColumn) Then
        With Comment
          .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
          If .Shape.Width > 300 Then
            lArea = .Shape.Width * .Shape.Height
            .Shape.Width = 200
            ' An adjustment factor of 1.1 seems to work ok.
            .Shape.Height = (lArea / 200) * 1.1
          End If
        End With
    End If
Next ' comment
End Sub
```

Alternatively you could loop through all the `Cells` of the range and determine `if cell.Comment Is Not Nothing` and then set the relevant comment if it is not nothing.

Though arguably if this would be faster than working on each comment?

You could contemplate trying to set `Application.Screenupdating = false` but that can be tricky.
(see also my answer here: [Screen Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74300223/2666502))

Comment: This solution worked superbly. Thankyou @mtholen  my original code's time overhead was 25 secs as it worked over a very large sheet. With your solution I was able to select 5 columns of interest, reducing the time overhead to 1 sec!!! Superb result.